# Extract String Part to Column in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, stringr

Consider the following dataframe:

```
     status
1    file-status-done-bad
2    file-status-maybe-good
3    file-status-underreview-good 
4    file-status-complete-final-bad
```

We want to extract the last part of status, wherein part is delimited by `-`. Such:

```
     status                          status_extract
1    file-status-done-bad            done
2    file-status-maybe-good          maybe
3    file-status-ok-underreview-good underreview
4    file-status-complete-final-bad  final
```

In SQL this is easy, `select split_part(status, '-',  -2)`.

However, the solutions I've seen with R either operate on vectors or are messy to extract particular elements (they return ALL elements). How is this done in a mutate chain? The below is a failed attempt.

```
df %>%
mutate(status_extract = str_split_fixed(status, pattern = '-')[[-2]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the a really simple answer.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(status_extract = word(status, -1, sep = "-"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` and `nth()` to extract the nth value from a vector.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(status_extract = map_chr(str_split(status, "-"), nth, -2))

#                           status status_extract
# 1           file-status-done-bad           done
# 2         file-status-maybe-good          maybe
# 3   file-status-underreview-good    underreview
# 4 file-status-complete-final-bad          final
```

which is equivalent to a `base` version like

```
sapply(strsplit(df$status, "-"), function(x) rev(x)[2])

# [1] "done"        "maybe"       "underreview" "final"
```

Comment: This works! It's strange to me that this isn't a single function in a major package like `stringr`

Comment: @PDog Yes, in my answer I use `map()` in `purrr` and `nth()` in `dplyr`. They are all in the `tidyverse` framework. I add a base R version, which doesn't need to load any external packages.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can combine the functions `sapply` and `strsplit`

```
df$status_extract <- sapply(strsplit(df$status, "-"), function(x) x[length(x) - 1])

#                           status status_extract
# 1           file-status-done-bad           done
# 2         file-status-maybe-good          maybe
# 3   file-status-underreview-good    underreview
# 4 file-status-complete-final-bad          final
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to get what you want without splitting the string.

```
sub('.*-(\\w+)-.*$', '\\1', df$status)
#[1] "done"        "maybe"       "underreview" "final"
```